# How to compile IronRuby into a Silverlight Application (XAP)?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime, scriptengine

I'm looking to possibly use IronRuby as the primary language for development of a Silverlight 4 application. I know there's the "IronRuby in the Browser" stuff that uses Gestalt, but I would like to build a standard Silverlight Applicatin using IronRuby and XAML that gets compiled into a XAP file, just like you can in C#.

Anyone know if there is a way to do this easily?

I have thought about a way to use the ScriptEngine to load/execute an IronRuby Resource file (.rb) on Application Startup that utilizes a XAML Resource (same as C# would) to get the application working. I have yet to try this method, and am wondering if anyone has tried anything similar or has another idea on how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: echo... echo... echo... Any body there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just must use Chiron.exe from IronRuby distr, like:

```
Chiron.exe /d:path_to_app /z:where_you_want_to_save/app.xap
```

and chiron generate app.xap file for your project